# Pusher not triggering event is not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, pusher, pusher-js

I am trying to trigger a pusher event but it's not working.

```
class SendWaitingForRedirect implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['my-channel'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }
}
```

and calling the event as

```
event(new \App\Events\SendWaitingForRedirect('hello world'));
```

I don't know what's wrong.
Can you please help?

I checked errors on the pusher. It is not having any errors.
Can you please help.

Comment: why to use event class that are provided by laravel framework...??

Answer (score 0):

You are not used the proper syntax of channel and event. The syntax is look like this

```
class SendWaitingForRedirect implements ShouldBroadcast
 {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
     return new Channel('my-channel');//Use the different type of channel as you want

}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return $this->message; //Return data as you want
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Got "Failed to connect to Pusher."